# Convex hull with constant size or triangular form

Tags: search, computational-geometry, convex-hull, pruning

I know QuickHull algorithm runs in Theta(n), if convex hull is triangular or it has constant size.

What's this means?

I'm not sure about the shape (if it looks a triangle), because the algorithm uses 4 extreme points.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the number of vertices of the convex hull, let `H`, is a constant (doesn't depend on `N`), then QuickHull takes a time proportional to `N` (more precisely `c1.N < T < c2.N` for two constants `c1` and `c2`).

When `H=3`, the hull is a triangle. Regardless the way the algorithm works, it has to return this triangle. Careful implementations should even work for `H=2` (a line segment) or `H=1` (a single point).